# FileInfo.MoveTo if file exists - rename

Tags: c#, fileinfo

I have an application that moves files from one directory to another, but sometimes a conflict occurs and the file already exists in the destination directory.

When that happens, I want to move the file with a different name - e.g. if the file is named `test.txt`, I want to name it `test.txt.1`. That's okay, but how do I do it next time, if the file is again `test.txt`, but in the destination folder we have both `test.txt` and `test.txt.1`.

My problem is that I can't find the last created file so that I can read its index and increment it with 1. Any suggestions?

```
string sourcePath = "C:\\Files\\test.txt";
string filename = Path.GetFileName(sourcePath);
string pathTo = "C:\\Files\\test\\" + filename;

try
{
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(sourcePath);
    fileInfo.MoveTo(pathTo);
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(sourcePath);
    var file = Directory.GetFiles(pathTo, filename+".1").FirstOrDefault();
    if (file == null)
    {
        fileInfo.MoveTo(pathTo+".1");
    }
    else
    {
        //find the old file, read it's last index and increment it with 1
    }

}
```

Comment: look at here = http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can not name files like that. The `1` would be the extension which obviously isn't possible. It should be text1.txt.

Comment: @Matthijs, why not? I can rename a file with `.1` extension in Windows Explorer. My idea is that I will have a backup of the file, and later I can rename it again if need to.

Comment: @Apostrofix, But why would you? It would lose its' integrity as .txt-file.

Comment: @Matthijs You can rename your file with .1 extenstion.But if you want to open the file in text editor you have to rename it again

Comment: @Matthijs and Naren, yes if I need to use the file, I will rename it again(move it to a new folder where it doesn't exist and rename, so no filename conflicts)

Comment: Do you specificially want the file that was last written to, or is the index the key to search for?

Comment: both of them are important, since there could be files with different names and i always need the last index, so that the data consistency in the files will be kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have rewritten your code a little because you were programming against the exception, which is something I really do not encourage.

First, it checks if the original file already exists.

Then, as your original code, it tries to create the file with a .1 indexer. If that is already present, it goes through the directory to locate all files that have the same filename.

Last, it goes to find the last index used and increments it by one.

Note that you could also skip the first if-statement in the else-statement because it will still search for the last index used; and if none is present, the lastIndex will stay 0 (with one increment so it will use 1 as index for the new file).

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(sourcePath);

// Check if the file already exists.
if (!fileInfo.Exists)
    fileInfo.MoveTo(pathTo);
else
{
    var file = Directory.GetFiles(pathTo, filename + ".1").FirstOrDefault();
    if (file == null)
    {
        fileInfo.MoveTo(pathTo + ".1");
    }
    else
    {
        // Get all files with the same name.
        string[] getSourceFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathTo)).Where(s => s.Contains(filename)).ToArray();

        // Retrieve the last index.
        int lastIndex = 0;
        foreach (string s in getSourceFileNames)
        {
            int currentIndex = 0;
            int.TryParse(s.Split('.').LastOrDefault(), out currentIndex);
            if (currentIndex > lastIndex)
                lastIndex = currentIndex;
        }

        // Do something with the last index.
        lastIndex++;
        fileInfo.MoveTo(pathTo + lastIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a function like this..

```
void MoveFileToPath(string sourceFilePath,string destinationDirectory)
    {
        int index = 1;
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath);
        string destPath = destinationDirectory+fileName;

        while(File.Exists(destPath))
        {
            destPath = string.Format("{0}{1}.{2}",destinationDirectory,fileName,index);
            index++;
        }
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(sourceFilePath);
        Console.WriteLine("Test:"+destPath);
        fileInfo.MoveTo(destPath);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Func<int, string> getFileName= delegate(int i) 
{
    return string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}.{3}", dir, filenameWithouExt, i, ext);
};

int i = 0;
while(File.Exists(getFileName(i)))
{
 i++;
}
fileInfo.MoveTo(getFileName(i));
```

It depends how much files do you have. You can make it more quicker if you have a lot of files:

```
int i = 0;
while(File.Exists(getFileName(i)))
{
  i+=100;
}
i-=90;

while(File.Exists(getFileName(i)))
{
  i+=10;
}
i-=9;

while(File.Exists(getFileName(i)))
{
  i+=1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to write a method that will return a next index for a file and remove try-catch block:

```
string sourcePath = "C:\\Files\\test.txt";
string filename = Path.GetFileName(sourcePath);
string pathTo = "C:\\Files\\test\\"; // the destination file name would be appended later

var fileInfo = new FileInfo(sourcePath);
if (!fileInfo.Exists)
{
    fileInfo.MoveTo(pathTo);
}
else
{
    // Get all files by mask "test.txt.*"
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(pathTo, string.Format("{0}.*", filename)).ToArray();
    var newExtension = GetNewFileExtension(files); // will return .1, .2, ... .N

    fileInfo.MoveTo(Path.Combine(pathTo, string.Format("{0}{1}", filename, newExtension)));
}
```

And the new method for getting the new index:

```
public static string GetNewFileExtension(string[] fileNames) 
{
    int maxIndex = 0;

    foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
    {
        // get the file extension and remove the "."
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName).Substring(1); 
        int parsedIndex;
        // try to parse the file index and do a one pass max element search
        if(int.TryParse(extension, out parsedIndex)) 
        {
            if(parsedIndex > maxIndex)
            {
                maxIndex = parsedIndex;
            }
        }
    }

    // increment max index by 1
    return string.Format(".{0}", maxIndex + 1); 
}
```